# Hyperlinks with anchors do not work on Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, internet-explorer, hyperlink, permalink

In Microsoft Excel, I go to a cell and create a hyperlink to a PDF document as follows:

```
http://example.com/MyDocument.pdf#page10
```

Unfortunately, when I click on it, my web browser (Chrome) goes to the following link:

```
http://example.com/MyDocument.pdf%20-%20page10
```

which of course returns 404: Not Found. The link does work as intended in Internet Explorer, but not in Chrome or Firefox.

Strangely, when I use any other kind of link with an anchor (which does not point to a PDF, for instance), it works fine. For instance, the following works:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#using-models
```

Comment: Which PDF plugin are you using for IE (where anchors work), and are you using the same for the other browsers too?

Comment: The documents are opened with Acrobat Reader X inside the browsers. No  browser-specific plug-ins are used.